# Extraer 4 Strings random de un Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, string

como podría extraer 4 strings aleatoriamente de de un array, por ejemplo este

```
var myArray = ["Rufles Original", "Aceitunas", "Lays al punto de sal", "Doritos TexMex", "Nachos", "Aceituna maceradas", 
           "Rufles Jamon Jamon", "Cerveza", "Coca-cola", "Kas naranja", "Pepinillos", "Banderillas", "Frutos secos",
           "Cacahuetes", "Mojitos" 
          ]
```

Y que no estuviesen repetidos. Luego los metería en un .html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elimina las posiciones que ya hayas elegido, para no modificar el array original, crea un array de posiciones y trabaja con esa.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var myArray = ["Rufles Original", "Aceitunas", "Lays al punto de sal", "Doritos TexMex", "Nachos", "Aceituna maceradas",
  "Rufles Jamon Jamon", "Cerveza", "Coca-cola", "Kas naranja", "Pepinillos", "Banderillas", "Frutos secos",
  "Cacahuetes", "Mojitos"
];
var cuatroRandom = [];
var posicionesElegibles = [];
var i, r;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) posicionesElegibles[i] = i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * posicionesElegibles.length);
  cuatroRandom.push(myArray[posicionesElegibles[r]]);
  posicionesElegibles.splice(r, 1);
}
console.log(cuatroRandom.toString());
```

Añado un método alternativo, este usa menos memoria ya que solo guarda las posiciones ya usadas para controlar que no se vuelvan a repetir, pero es un poco mas lenta ya que hace búsquedas dentro la matriz de control.
Depende del problema puede ser mas apropiado un sistema u otro.

```js
var myArray = ["Rufles Original", "Aceitunas", "Lays al punto de sal", "Doritos TexMex", "Nachos", "Aceituna maceradas", 
           "Rufles Jamon Jamon", "Cerveza", "Coca-cola", "Kas naranja", "Pepinillos", "Banderillas", "Frutos secos",
           "Cacahuetes", "Mojitos" 
          ];
 
var cuatroRandom=[];
var posicionesElegidas=[];
var i,j,r,c;
for (i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++){
 r = Math.floor(Math.random()*(myArray.length-posicionesElegidas.length))+1;
 c = 0;
 j = 0;
 do if (posicionesElegidas.indexOf(j++)==-1) c++; while(c<r);
 j--;
 cuatroRandom.push(myArray[j]);
 posicionesElegidas.push(j);
}
 console.log(cuatroRandom.toString());
```

Un tercer método, que es una mezcla de los dos, y podría ser el más rápido pues no añade ni quita valores en ningún array, y consumiría menos memoria que el primero pues guarda booleanos en vez de posiciones, seria crear una matriz de control de posiciones, inicializandolas todas a true, e ir apagando a medida que se usan.

```js
var myArray = ["Rufles Original", "Aceitunas", "Lays al punto de sal", "Doritos TexMex", "Nachos", "Aceituna maceradas", 
           "Rufles Jamon Jamon", "Cerveza", "Coca-cola", "Kas naranja", "Pepinillos", "Banderillas", "Frutos secos",
           "Cacahuetes", "Mojitos" 
          ];
 
var cuatroRandom=[];
var posicionesElegibles=[];
var posiciones=myArray.length;
posicionesElegibles.length=posiciones;
posicionesElegibles.fill(true);
var i,j,r,c;
var contadorElegidas=0;
for (i=0; i<4;i++){
 r=Math.floor(Math.random()*(posiciones-contadorElegidas))+1;
 c=0;
 j=0;
 do if (posicionesElegibles[j++])c++; while(c<r);
 j--;
 cuatroRandom.push(myArray[j]);
 posicionesElegibles[j]=false;
 contadorElegidas++;
}
 console.log(cuatroRandom.toString());
```

Comment: Con este código me extrae 4 items correctamente, pero repite algunos items en el misma respuesta. Lo que quiero es que todos sean únicos.

Comment: Perdón, orden de parámetros incorrecto XD, ya está.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo otras alternativas :

```js
var myArray = [
  "Rufles Original", "Aceitunas", "Lays al punto de sal", "Doritos TexMex", "Nachos",   
  "Aceituna maceradas","Rufles Jamon Jamon", "Cerveza", "Coca-cola", "Kas naranja", "Pepinillos",
  "Banderillas", "Frutos secos","Cacahuetes", "Mojitos" 
];

function getRandomString(array){
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]
}

function getRandomStrings(numero, array){
  var strings = [];
  while(strings.length < numero){
    var string = getRandomString(array);
    if(strings.indexOf(string) == -1) strings.push(string);
  }
  return strings;
}

console.log(getRandomStrings(4, myArray));
```

**EDIT**

Gracias a los comentarios de Arnau, te porpongo otra solución sin utilizar el bucle while y cogiendo en cada loop los elementos que aún no se han añadido :

```js
var myArray = [
  "Rufles Original", "Aceitunas", "Lays al punto de sal", "Doritos TexMex", "Nachos",   
  "Aceituna maceradas","Rufles Jamon Jamon", "Cerveza", "Coca-cola", "Kas naranja", "Pepinillos",
  "Banderillas", "Frutos secos","Cacahuetes", "Mojitos" 
];


function getRandomStrings(number, array){
  var strings = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
    var validValues = array.filter(el => !strings.includes(el) );
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * validValues.length);
    strings.push(validValues[rand])
  }
  return strings;
}

console.log(getRandomStrings(myArray.length - 1, myArray));
```

Comment: Espero que no te lo tomes mal, pero este tipo de soluciones, que repiten hasta conseguirlo, no son... como decirlo... "matematicamente elegantes", ya que no puedes saber que va a tardar en conseguirlo, ni si quiera si va a hacerlo (teóricamente).
Evidentemente este ejemplo no causa ningún problema, pero imagínate que la lista tiene un millón de valores y quieres 999.999 (o todos), para colocar el último valor estaría repitiendo el bucle hasta que el random acierte uno entre un millón.

Comment: No me lo tomo a mal cuando alguien tiene razón y en este caso la tienes, pero también estás poniendo un caso extremo. Trataré de mejorar la respuesta! Pensé en la legibilidad a la hora de escibir el código! Saludos! =)

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Arreglado! =)

Comment: El "verdadero" problema, el que te puedes encontrar en la vida real, es que este tipo de soluciones no son aceptadas en una carrera, o como mínimo te quitarían puntos. Y tengo miedo que un estudiante universitario las use, y suspenda un examen XD

Comment: La verdad es que tienes razón, a veces hacemos las cosas sin pensar y suelen surgir estos probelmas. Por eso me gusta este tipo de foros, alguien con buena voluntad como tú está dispuesto a ayudarte a mejorar! Saludos! =)