# ¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?

Tags: javascript

Hice un `array` o arreglo para tener 5 valores.

Simplemente quiero que aparezcan aleatorios con un `random math`...pero..
el detalle es que a veces pasa que se repite el mismo valor 1 hasta 3 veces seguidas yo no quiero eso. Ejemplo:

En el arreglo dice 12345. cuando se ejecuta sale 11 luego 4 3 5..... pero el 1 se repitió dos veces seguidas, ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que no pase eso?

Comment: cuando puedas agrega el código que has intentado hacer.

Comment: @Alan su codigo seguramente es un **bucle for** que itera tantas veces como longitud tenga el array pero sin comprobar que el valor seleccionado ha sido seleccionado antes.

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 12):

la forma más sencilla que he encontrado y que vi en [esta pagina](https://www.ngeeks.com/javascript-avanzado-desordenar-un-array/):

```
var lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
lista = lista.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});
document.write(lista); // imprime por ejemplo: 7,9,1,5,2,3,6,4,8
```

Funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 10):

Esta es una forma de obtener números aleatorios sin que se repitan a partir de un array definido, en este caso como ejemplo 5 valores.

```js
var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5'];

    var i,j,k;
    for (i = myArray.length; i; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        k = myArray[i - 1];
        myArray[i - 1] = myArray[j];
        myArray[j] = k;
    }


document.write("números aleatorios : " + myArray);
```

---

Esta es una forma para obtener números aleatorios sin que se repitan, lo que tienes que realizar es obtener un número aleatorio en el rango definido y verificar no se repita almacenando en un array, un ejemplo obteniendo números aleatorios en un rango de 1 a 5:

```js
//Define la cantidad de numeros aleatorios.
var cantidadNumeros = 5;
var myArray = []
while(myArray.length < cantidadNumeros ){
  var numeroAleatorio = Math.ceil(Math.random()*cantidadNumeros);
  var existe = false;
  for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
 if(myArray [i] == numeroAleatorio){
        existe = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(!existe){
    myArray[myArray.length] = numeroAleatorio;
  }

}
document.write("números aleatorios : " + myArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

Lo que pienso es, que del array `[1,2,3,4,5]`, quitar el elemento `1`, y ponerlo en una posición aleatoria del segundo array, entonces queda `[1]`.

Luego el `2`, y ponerlo aleatoriamente, y puede quedar `[2,1]` o `[1,2]`. Si es `[2,1]`, luego el `3`, puede quedar `[3,2,1]`, `[2,3,1]` o `[2,1,3]`. Si es `[2,1,3]`, luego el `4`, entonces `[4,2,1,3] [2,4,1,3] [2,1,4,3] [2,1,3,4]`. Si es `[2,4,1,3]`.

Por último, el `5` puede insertarse en algún lugar, quedando estos posibles arrays.

```
[5,2,4,1,3]
[2,5,4,1,3]
[2,4,5,1,3]
[2,4,1,5,3]
[2,4,1,3,5]
```

Suponiendo que se insertó en la cuarta posición, el array resultante es `[2,4,1,5,3]`. Matemáticamente, los arrays posibles para x es **x!**, es decir, el factorial de x, es decir, para 5 son 120 posibilidades, mientras que si se repiten los números es x<sup>x</sup>, es decir, para 5 son 3125 posibilidades.

Código:

```js
function insertarEn(array,valor,posición)
{
 var inicio=array.slice(0,posición)
 var medio=valor
 var fin=array.slice(posición)
 var resultado=inicio.concat(medio).concat(fin)
 return resultado
}
function aleatoriosNoRepetidos(cantidad)
{
 var array=[]
 for(var i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
 {
  array=insertarEn(array,i,Math.random()*(cantidad+1) )
 }
 return array
}
console.log( aleatoriosNoRepetidos(5)+"" )
```

Answer (score 4):

Respondí una pregunta similar en otro hilo:
[Extraer 4 Strings random de un Array en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22857/extraer-4-strings-random-de-un-array-en-javascript/22865#comment36604_22865)
La idea es almacenar los números ya aparecidos y elegir los números de los restantes.
EDIT:
Ejemplo de función, introduces el mínimo y máximo, y elige números al azar hasta que se terminan las opciones, si se activa el reset, resetea la lista, si se cambia el rango también.

```js
 function numAleatorioSinRepetir(minimo,maximo) {
  var i;
  if (minimo=="reset"){ // Si el primer parámetro es "reset", reinicia la lista de números y sale.
   if (!this.minimo||!this.maximo) return; // Si el rango no está definido, sale.
   this.numerosAparecidos=[]; // reinicia matriz
   for (i=this.minimo;i<=this.maximo;i++)
    this.numerosAparecidos.push(i); // Introduce los números del rango.
   return;
  }
  if (isNaN(minimo)||isNaN(maximo)) return; // Si los parámetros no son números, sale.

  if (minimo!=this.minimo || maximo!=this.maximo){ // Si cambia el rango, resetea la lista de numeros.
   if (minimo>maximo) { // Si el mínimo es mayor que el máximo, invierte las variables.
    i=minimo;
    minimo=maximo;
    maximo=i;
   }
   this.minimo=minimo; // Guarda el nuevo rango
   this.maximo=maximo;
   this.numerosAparecidos=[]; // reinicia matriz
   for (i=minimo;i<=maximo;i++)
    this.numerosAparecidos.push(i); // Introduce los números del rango.
  }
  var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*this.numerosAparecidos.length); // Elije una posicion aleatoria
  var numero=this.numerosAparecidos[random]; // Guarda el número de la posición.
  this.numerosAparecidos.splice(random,1); // Elimina la posición.
  return numero; // Devuelve el número.
 }
 function ponNumero(){
  var min=parseInt(IDmin.value);
  var max=parseInt(IDmax.value);
  var numero=numAleatorioSinRepetir(min,max);
  IDinfo.innerHTML+=numero+", ";
 }
```

```html
Mínimo:<input id="IDmin"> Máximo:<input id="IDmax"> <button onclick="numAleatorioSinRepetir('reset')">Reset</button>
<button onclick="ponNumero()">Pon numero</button>
<DIV id="IDinfo"></DIV>
```

Comment: @ArnauCastellví hola, el comentario lo pone automáticamente la revisión, de todos modos siempre es bueno dejar un ejemplo por eso revisé tu publicación. así queda todo en esta pregunta, si la otra es borrada te quedaría incompleta, gracias por agregar elejemplo!

Comment: @ArnauCastellví tómalo como sugerencia no estoy tratando de decir que es mala la respuesta, es mas me parece buena, solo son críticas constructivas :), +1

Answer (score 4):

Esta es una forma simple de llenar un arreglo con números aleatorios, con variables para parametrizar lo que necesites.

```js
var arr = []; // Arreglo para llenar
var cantidadNumeros = 5; // Cantidad de números en el arreglo
var hasta = 10; // Máximo valor de los números en el arreglo

function llenarAleatorios(a){
    var v = Math.floor(Math.random() * hasta);
    if(!a.some(function(e){return e == v})){
        /** 
         * Si no se encuentra el valor aleatorio en el arreglo
         * se pushea el valor.
         */ 
        a.push(v);
    }
}
/**
 * Bucle para llenar el arreglo con la cantidad que necesites
 */
while(arr.length < cantidadNumeros && cantidadNumeros < hasta){
    llenarAleatorios(arr);
}
```

Luego de esto, tenes tu arreglo lleno de **números aleatorios no repetidos**.

Answer (score 3):

Sacado de SO ENG: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/3045491

El método te lo "baraja", reordena los elementos.

```
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias, intentare agregarlo a mi codigo, a ver si jala, no entiendo bien esa logica  lois6

Comment: es que sin añadir tú tu codigo ... la cosa es que si en tu codigo coges 5 numeros aleatorios, te van a salir repetidos. añade un array donde metas los que has ido seleccionando para comprobar que no han sido elegidos ya

Comment: El titulo de la pregunta dice "_¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?_". Esta respuesta no genera los números.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo la pregunta empieza con "Hice un array o arreglo para tener 5 valores.". Por lo que parece el OP quiere pasar un array con los valores a "randomizar"

Comment: Esto: "_para tener 5 valores_", sumado al titulo, se puede entender como: al finalizar el `script` quiere tener *5 valores*.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo mirate la pregunta, mirate las respuestas y vuelve a pensarlo otra vez.

Comment: Leo la pregunta, miro las respuestas y esta es la única que no genera los número.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo la respuesta de arteze, Elenasys, la mía y **sobretodo** la pregunta del OP. Pon tu propia respuesta si lo consideras oportuno. Un saludo

Comment: @Memo333, puedes por favor leeer mi conversación con Marcos y dar luz al asunto ?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar closures para crear tu propio generador de numeros aleatorios basado en una lista de elementos.

En el siguiente código te muestro como crear una función cuyo parámetro es una lista.

Esa lista es "barajada" en el bucle for (al acabar el bucle for, los elementos estarán desordenados al azar).

Una vez hecho esto, la función devuelve otra función que se encargará de darte un número aleatorio distinto de esa lista en cada llamada, de manera circular (cuando te devuelva todos los que tiene sin repetir, volverá a empezar a dártelos en el mismo orden previo).

```
var randomFromListGenerator = function (list) {
    var position = 0;

    for (var i=0, l=list.length; i<l; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * l));
        var aux = list[i];
        list[i] = list[random];
        list[random] = aux;
    }

    return function () {
        return list[position++ % list.length];
    }
}
```

Para usar esta función solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
var nextRandomFromList = randomFromListGenerator ([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Y cuando quieras un nuevo número aleatorio hacer:

```
var newRandom = nextRandomFromList();
```

Con esto puedes implementar este comportamiento con cuantas listas quieras. Puedes modificar la función para que te lance un error cuando ya te devolvió todos los valores de la lista o para que rebaraje la lista y obtener un nuevo orden para que no sea siempre "circular".

Answer (score 3):

Lo siguiente puede ser un buen comienzo para ti:

Defines un `array` con los elementos que deseas obtener de manera aleatoria y defines una variable que contendrá el ultimo valor obtenido aunque inicialmente no tendrá asociado ningún valor.

Luego llamas a la función `getRandomFromArrayNotRepeated` pasandole como argumento el array a elección. La misma Buscara un valor aleatorio del `array` y lo comparara con el ultimo valor asignado a `lastRandomValue`. Si los valores coinciden, se ejecutara nuevamente la función `getRandomFromArrayNotRepeated`, en caso de no coincidir asignara el nuevo valor a `lastRandomValue` y retornara dicho valor.

Si el array contiene un solo valor posible, siempre recibirás ese como resultado.

```js
var lastRandomValue, exampleArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function getRandomFromArrayNotRepeated(array) {
   var item = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
   if(lastRandomValue === item && array.length > 1) {
       return getRandomFromArrayNotRepeated(array, item);
   } 
   return lastRandomValue = item;
}

for(var i = 0, len = 100; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(getRandomFromArrayNotRepeated(exampleArray));
}
```

Si lo que en realidad quieres hacer es hacer cada valor aleatorio único (poder recibirlo ese valor solo una vez), Te recomiendo seguir esta solucion: [Generating non-repeating random numbers in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806417/3219633)

Answer (score 2):

Dejo esto por aquí, pueden colocar los parámetros que quieran.
Si colocan mal los parámetros la función hace un console.log para indicarles el problema.

Creo un arreglo vacío para usarlo con comodidad fuera de la función
La función rellenará el arreglo vacío con elementos distintos y aleatorios

Agrego un condicional para evitar que se generé un bucle infinito si por ejemplo se pasan parámetros pidiendo un arreglo de 20 elementos cuyo valor máximo de los elementos sea 10, como estamos tratando solo con enteros sería imposible generar ello.

do while nos permite ejecutar una o más funciones de manera repetitiva hasta que ya no se cumpla una condición que nosotros le damos.(revisar documentación)
Aplico el método some (revisar documentación)  para saber si alguno de los elementos de mi arreglo que se va llenando es igual al número aleatorio que estoy generando, si alguno es igual me retornará un valor "true" entonces aprovecho esa información para crear una variable ValidNumber que hago que sea igual al valor contrario de lo que me retorna some, es decir si lo que me retorna some es "false" ValidNumber es "true"  esto me dice que el número aleatorio generado es valido (no es igual a ningún elemento que ya posee el arreglo) para incluirlo en el arreglo.

Luego aplico la función con los parámetros que quiera y debido a que el arreglo que llené está fuera de la función lo puedo utilizar a mi comodidad.

```js
let randomNumberArray = []

const arrayOfDistinctRandomNumbers = (arrayLength,maxValue)=>{

 if((arrayLength - 1) <= maxValue){

   do {

      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxValue+1))
      let condition = (el)=>{return el == randomNumber}
      let validNumber = !randomNumberArray.some(condition)

      if(validNumber){randomNumberArray.push(randomNumber)}
                    
      }
        while (randomNumberArray.length < arrayLength)

  console.log(`Arreglo con "${randomNumberArray.length}" valores`)
  console.log(`Arreglo aleatorio solicitado: ${randomNumberArray}`) 

  }else{
        console.log('"arrayLength -1" no puede ser mayor que el maxValue')
  }
             
}

arrayOfDistinctRandomNumbers(5,9)

let arreglo = randomNumberArray.join(',')
document.querySelector('.array').textContent = `Resultado: [ ${arreglo} ]`
```

```css
.container{
width:100%;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
padding-top:50px;
}
.array{
font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="array"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Un poco más de detalles del código ayudaría bastante

Answer (score 2):

Hice este ejercicio para 500 números aleatorios que no se repitan, donde los números deben ser de cuatro dígitos.

```js
//Cantidad de numeros aleatorios a generar.
var cantidadNumeros = 500;

//Array donde se Guardarán los números únicos.
var myArray = [];

//Loop hasta que se cumpla la condición
while (myArray.length < cantidadNumeros) {
  var numeroAleatorio = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000).toString();

  //Verificamos que el número a evaluar tenga 4 cifras.
  if (numeroAleatorio.length == 4) {
    //Filtramos el valor
    var existe = myArray.filter((r) => r == numeroAleatorio);

    //Sino existe
    if (existe.length == 0) {
      //Agregamos el número al array.
      myArray.push(parseInt(numeroAleatorio));
    }
  }
}
//Imprimimos en consola.
console.log("myArray", myArray);

//Mostramos en la pag.
myArray.forEach((item) => {
  document.write(" " + item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui coloco un aporte para la generacion de numeros aleatorios sin que se repitan:

Yo aborde el problema desde el siguiente punto de vista:

1) el valor maximo del random debera ser igual a la cantidad de numero a la cantidad de numeros solicitados para que tenga sentido la generacion y no quede sin numeros.

2) se genera el valor aleatorio y se crea un arreglo llamado "array".

3) se compara los valores del arreglo con el numero generado, si no existe se agrega.

4) se termina el ciclo con la cantidad de numeros solicitados
Array(4) [ 0, 4, 3, 1 ]

5) se crea un arreglo vacio con la cantidad de numeros solicitados el arreglo se llama "foo"

6) se inserta  en el arreglo "foo"los numeros generados y almacenados por el arreglo "array' deacuerdo a su valor y posicion en el indice quedando casillas indefinidas.
Ejemplo:
Array(5) [ 0, 1, <1 empty slot>, 3, 4 ]

7) se hace un recorrido por el arreglo "foo" para buscar las casilla indefinidas y las que se encuentra se inserta como valor la posicion encontrada, quedando el arreglo final de esta forma.
Array(5) [ 0, 4, 3, 1, 2 ]

Nota: no se puso a generar al random cada vez que encontraba un numero repetido porque esto al final consume ciclo de proceso y hasta puede entrar en un bucle indefinido al tratar de generar un numero que posiblemente no salga en el random.

ADJUNTO EL CODIGO:

```js
// declaracion de variables
   var veces = 5;
   var max = veces;

    var array =[];
    for(var l=0; l< veces; l++) {          
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max); 
                 var repite=false;
                // busca la lista de numeros generados
                array.forEach(function(element) {
                     // si hay un numero repetido  = TRUE
                     if (element==randomNumber) {
                        repite=true;
                        }
                });           
                // si no se repite ningun numero = FALSE
                if (repite==false) {
                    array.push(randomNumber)
                }       
    }

    
    console.log(array); // valor de arreglo array

    // crear array por numero de veces
    var foo = new Array(veces);    
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        foo[element]= element;
    });
    console.log(foo); // arreglo foo

    // buscar campo indefinidos para completar 
    for (let index = 0; index < foo.length; index++) {
       console.log(foo[index]);
       if (foo[index]=== undefined) {
         console.log('indefinido valor');
         array.push(index);
       }
    }
    
    console.log(array); // resultado de arreglo;

    // mostrar valor en mensaje
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        document.writeln(element)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice una forma con una función y considero que es bastante buena ya que esta bastante comprimida

```
`function aleatorio(min,maxi)
{
var resultado;
resultado = Math.round(Math.random() *(maxi - min + 1));
return resultado;
}`
```

Ya simplemente puedes agregarla a un for() si es que tu caso lo nececita.

Comment: Pero esta respuesta garantiza que los números no se repitan?

Comment: Yo considero que depende del uso que le vayas a dar se puede llegar a diferentes soluciones en mi caso la ocupe para generar cordenas aleatorias  para asi poder una imagen sobre un canvas de forma aleatoria if (gorgon.cargaOK)
  {
      for (var v = 0; v < cantidad; v++) {
    var x = aleatorio(0,5)
    var y = aleatorio(0,5)
    var x = x* 80;
    var y =  y* 80;
    papel.drawImage(gorgon.objeto,x,y);
      }

Comment: al multiplicar y *80 & x * 80 se generaba un espacio entre imágenes

Answer (score -1):

Primero crea una lista con la cantidad de número que deseas.

```
Lis<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_que_quieres; i++) {
                    numbers.add(i);
                }
```

Luego le pones shuffle.

```
                Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Y luego lo recorres (y estará desordenado gracias al shuffle). Es decir que si
en el i < tu_variable pusiste 10, tendrás 10 números desordenados.

Y luego pides el rango de números que quieres. ¿A qué me refiero? Que en el límite de arriba pueden ser 100, porque aunque quieras al final mostrar 3 en total, no quisieras que también se limitara a 3 aleatorios. Arriba defines cuántos quieres y aquí abajo defines cuántos mostrarás y en qué rango. Si quieres iniciar desde 1, j=1 y así.

```
    for(int j=0;j<total_rango;j++){
 //Muestras el indice j, que será aleatorio y no se repetirá
}
```

Comment: todo este codigo esta en linea? tengo ke poner algo en el for ??

Comment: Los for están separados. Para mostrar entonces pones print(numbers.get[j]) y te mostrará el índice de numbers (que contiene números desordenados y no repetidos) en el que j esté en el momento.

Comment: @Jonny la pregunta está etiquetada como [javascript] (Y JavaScript no es Java).