# Generación de números aleatorios sin repetición en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando generar 5 números al azar al estilo de una loteria, el problema es que ningún numero puede ser igual a otro número anterior.

Por ejemplo `num1` no puede ser igual a `num2`, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de comprobar que estos nunca sean iguales.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```js
var num1 = Math.random() * 49
if (num1 == num0) {
  var num1 = Math.random() * 49
};
```

A pesar de eso cada tanto hay un número que se repite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genera un array con los números posibles, por ejemplo digamos que los números válidos van del 1 al 40

```
const n = 40;
const arr = new Array(n);
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Ordénalos al azar

```
arr.sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);
```

Y luego toma solo 5

```
const loteria = arr.slice(0, 5);
```

Ejemplo:

```js
const n = 40;
const arr = new Array(n);
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}

arr.sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);
const loteria = arr.slice(0, 5);

document.write(loteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

Este Script te puede generar 5 números aleatorios.

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5'];

     var i,j,k;
     for (i = myArray.length; i; i--) {
         j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
         k = myArray[i - 1];
         myArray[i - 1] = myArray[j];
         myArray[j] = k;
     }

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArray;
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La idea es almacenar los números aparecidos para comprobar que no han aparecido antes.
-El sistema "sencillo" seria que, en caso de repetir número, busque otro, pero este no es un método "elegante" ya que en el caso de querer "muchos" números puede darse el caso que tenga que repetir "muchas" veces.
-El sistema "elegante" se basa en crear una matriz con las opciones posibles e ir eliminandolos a medida que aparecen.
Respondí una pregunta similar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27555/3440

Answer (score 0):

Podrías almacenar todos los números que aparecen en un String separados por algún carácter y después buscar si el nuevo número está contenido en el String.

Si está contenido en el String, que vuelva a generar otro número y si no, que introduzca el valor generado. En mi caso he preferido utilizar un bucle do-while para asegurarme de que no salga del bucle hasta que obtenga un valor que no esté repetido.

Para hacer las 5 repeticiones puedes utilizar un bucle `for`.

Ejemplo:

```
var num1;
var cadena = "";

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    do{
       num1 = Math.random() * 49;
    }while(cadena.indexOf(num1) !== -1);

    cadena += num1 + "/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbersInUse = []
var randomNumbers = []
i = 0;
while(i < 5){
 var num = Math.random() * 49;
 if(!numbersInUse.indexOf(num) > -1){
    i++;
    numbersInUse.push(num);
    randomNumbers.push(num);
 }
}
console.log(randomNumbers);
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con

```
    var numeros = [];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        numeros[i]= String(Math.random()).substr(2, 16);

}
```

La longitud es de 14 puede cambiar eso modificando el 16

hay tienes 5 números aleatorio almacenados en un array

Comment: Esto lo aplico a todos los if o tengo que cambiar algo, ya que tengo 5 variables necesito comprobar para las 5 que no sean iguales entre ellas.
Soy bastante nuevo en JavaScript.

Comment: Pues te puedo asegurar que no van a hacer iguales

Comment: Pues me salen números iguales cada tanto,
var num0=Math.random()*49
var num1=Math.random()*49 
if (num1==num0) {
String(Math.random()).substr(2, 16);
   };
    
var num2=Math.random()*49
if (num2==num0||num2==num1) {
String(Math.random()).substr(2, 16);
   };

Answer (score -1):

Lo que yo haría, siguiendo el principio de *reutilización de código*, sería crear una función que admitiera como parámetro la cantidad de números aleatorios a generar, para el caso 5, y las cifras que deben tener éstos números. Por supuesto habría que comprobar luego como conviven ambos valores (no se puede pedir 200 números diferentes y pedir números de sólo 2 cifras, por ejemplo).

Internamente ésta función debería generar números, aleatoria mente, rellenando una array hasta la cantidad requerida. Seguidamente se comprueban los números del array desde el principio y en caso de encontrar un duplicado sustituirlo por un nuevo número y volver a empezar, hasta comprobar todos los números del array.