# Como creo un array aleatorio de numero del 1 al 100 sin repetirlos

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy haciendo un bingo y me gustaría crear el cartón con 15 números del 1 al 100 sin repetirlos. Javascript
Se agradece cualquier tipo de ayuda

Comment: SERÍAS tan amable de agregar lo que haz intentado?

Comment: puedes probar con esto que genera un numero entre 1 y 100 aunque aun estoy checando para que sean números dentro de un array let numero = Math.round((Math.random() *100) /1)

console.log(numero)

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-generar-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan)

Comment: te sugiero leas y adaptes la primer respuesta de esta pregunta ya que te puede ser de mucha utilidad saludos https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-generar-n%C3%BAmeros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan

Answer (score 1):

La primera función nos devuelve un número que no tengamos en el array, la segunda nos genera un array con 100 elementos obtenidos con la función de arriba, espero que te sirva.

```js
    function getRnd(numberArr) {
        let newNumber;
        while (!newNumber || numberArr.includes(newNumber)) {
            newNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        }
        return newNumber;
    }


    function generateNumbers() {
        const numberArr = [];
        while (numberArr.length !== 100) {
            const n = getRnd(numberArr);
            numberArr.push(n);
        }
        return numberArr;
    }
    
    console.log(generateNumbers());
```

Comment: Buenas.
La primera función nos devuelve un número que no tengamos en el array, la segunda nos genera un array con 100 elementos obtenidos con la función de arriba, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por contribuir Jaime, agrega la explicación a tu respuesta, revisar [answer], saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Perdona, ya está la explicación. Un saludo