# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un arreglo con el índice de cada elemento dinámico?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, aplicación-web

### Tengo la siguiente aplicación:

---

Al presionar ***Click*** cada una de las letras que está en el input se convierte en un elemento independiente de un Array al cual con un `array.forEach()` creé un párrafo por cada letra y le agregé una clase para los estilos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es que al momento que el usuario dé click en el botón ***Disorder All*** la posición de cada elemento del array vaya cambiando de forma dinámica cada vez que el botón se presione.

Hasta el momento solo escrbí este código sin saber muy bien lo que hacía :D...

```js
      buttonDisorder.onclick = function() {
         // array.forEach(element => {

         // });

         for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            const element = array[i] = n;
            console.log(element);
         }
      };
```

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer esot, por favor y gracias!!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-generar-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes crear una función que te desordene el *array* intercambiando sus valores cierto número de veces, lo que te permitirá indicar *como* de desordenado lo quieres:

```js
const arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' ];

console.log( 'Original:', ...arr );
disorder( arr );
console.log( 'Desordenado:', ...arr );


function disorder( arr, steps ) {
  if( ( !steps ) || ( steps < 1 ) ) { steps = arr.length; }
  
  for( let count = 0; count < steps; ++count ) {
    let p1 = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * arr.length );
    let p2 = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * arr.length );
    let tmp = arr[p1];

    arr[p1] = arr[p2];
    arr[p2] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta es mi respuesta:
Por favor lea los comentarios de mi código.

La idea es esta: creas un array vacío `let desordenado = []` en el cual mueves uno por uno y de manera aleatoria los elementos del array inicial (`ry`). Para no mover dos veces el mismo elemento lo borras del array inicial.

```js
//el array inicial
const ry = "Lorem Ipsum".split("");
// el array desordenado: por ahora vacío
let desordenado = []
// mientras que la longitud de ry > 0
while(ry.length > 0){
//encuentra un número aleatorio
let j = ~~(Math.random()*ry.length);
//coge la letra ry[j] i ponla en el array desordenado
desordenado.push(ry[j]);
// y borrala del array ry
ry.splice(j,1)
}
console.log(ry,desordenado)
```

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow por comentar. La explicación está en los comentarios del código.

Comment: pero en general, puedes explicar el método? explicas que hace, pero no cómo soluciona lo que el OP pregunta, algo tipo "lo que te faltaba hacer es X cosa, yo lo hago así"...

Comment: @L.Ronquillo: he añadido una pequeña explicación aunque creo que los comentarios del codigo son suficientes para entender de que va. Gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 3):

Librerias como [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#shuffle) o [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#shuffle) te ayudan a muchas operaciones con arreglo , te lo recomiendo por si necesitas hacer algo mas complejo

```js
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' ];
const x = _.shuffle(arr)
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```