# Eliminar elementos repetidos de un array

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmos

Necesito eliminar los elementos repetidos de un array, pero me borra el campo o lo coloca vacío.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
for (var ib = 0; ib <= Idborrar.length; ib++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < Idborrar.length - 1; j++) {
    if (ib != j) {
      if (Idborrar[ib] == Idborrar[j]) {
        Idborrar[ib] = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo correctamente?

Comment: no quiero que los valores repetidos deseos eliminarlos del arreglo

Comment: Browser.msgBox(Idborrar.join("|"));contador = defaultIndex();
  for (var ib = 0; ib <= Idborrar.length; ib++){
      var valorUF = sheetasp.getLastRow();
  for (var x= contador; x < valorUF; x++ ){
      var valorAC= sheetasp.getRange(x,1).getValue();     
      if(valorAC == Idborrar[ib]){
      sheetasp.deleteRow(x);
      contador= x-1;
      break;
      }
    }
   }
}

Comment: relacionado : [¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-generar-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan)

Comment: tienes que recorrer el array al reves y hacer un splice `if (Idborrar[ib] == Idborrar[j]) {
        Idborrar.splice(ib, 1);
      }`

Answer (score 25):

Si tu "engine"  soporta  ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262), como es el caso de los navegadores modernos, como se sugiere en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/273733/65) de Fernando, usa `Set`, en caso contrario, sigue leyendo.

Para devolver un arreglo (Array) que incluya únicamente los valores únicos puedes usar lo siguiente (tomado de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/1595451) a [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/1595451) )

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// ejemplo de uso:
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter( onlyUnique ); // devuelve ['a', 1, 2, '1']
console.info(unique)
```

---

Por otro lado, si no quieres crear un nuevo objeto de tipo Array, sino modificar el objeto actual puedes usar algo como lo siguiente:

```js
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
for(var i = a.length -1; i >=0; i--){
  if(a.indexOf(a[i]) !== i) a.splice(i,1);
}
console.info(a)
```

Cabe hacer notar que el recorrido del iterable se realiza en forma invertida. Esto se hace así porque al eliminar un elemento del iterable cambia su tamaño y cambian los índices de los elementos siguientes, si bien es posible manejar esto con un bucle hacia adelante se vuelve más complejo pues hay que ajustar el iterador lo cual es muy proclive a errores.

---

Si fuera el caso que por eliminar los valores se está buscando hacerlo sin modificar el tamaño del objeto Array, es decir, reemplazar el valor por una cadena vacía usa algo como lo siguiente:

```js
function reemplazarDuplicados(value, index, self) { 
    return (self.indexOf(value) === index)?value:'';
}

// ejemplo de uso:
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var b = a.map( reemplazarDuplicados ); // devuelve ['a', 1, 2, '1']
console.info(b)
```

Por otro lado, si no quieres crear un nuevo objeto de tipo Array, sino modificar el objeto actual *asignando un cadena vacía* puedes usar algo como lo siguiente:

```js
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
for(var i = a.length -1; i >=0; i--){
  if(a.indexOf(a[i]) !== i) a[i] = '';
}
console.info(a)
```

Answer (score 18):

Quizás te interese conocer algo sobre el objeto [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set), que te permite almacenar los valores únicos de cualquier tipo.

De esta forma, en una línea, sin tu programar las iteraciones ni nada extraño, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 'a', 6, 6, 'a']; // Si lo que quieres es reasignarlo, puedes usar let en lugar de const

const myUniqueArray = [...new Set(myArray)]; // myArray = [...new Set(myArray)];

console.log(myUniqueArray); // console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Sencillo y elegante, buena respuesta

Comment: lo unico para aclarar,  que no hagas la iteracion tu, no quiere decir que el `new Set()` tampoco lo  haga, al decir "sin iteraciones" estas mintiendo generalmente tienen eficiencia algoritmica[O(n log n)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_algor%C3%ADtmica#An%C3%A1lisis_Te%C3%B3rico)

Comment: @jacknavarow me refiero a que te abstraerse de hacer la iteración manual, para el desarrollador eso es "transparente" no tiene que implementar el ningun bucle.

Comment: solo aclaro @FernandoCarrascosa, no quiere decir que no me guste tu respuesta

Comment: Originalmente la pregunta sólo tenía la etiqueta [tag:google-apps-script] pero como no se mencionó en el cuerpo del mensaje nada relacionado con esta la reemplacé pero ahora que veo tu respuesta creo que es pertinente que se mencione que `Set` se introdujo en ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262) y si el OP estuviera usando google-apps-script este no es soportado.

Comment: bueno bien ahora use la funcion  for(var  ib=0;  ib<Idborrar.length; ib++){
   if (Idborrar.indexOf(Idborrar[ib])!== ib) Idborrar.splice(ib, 1);
  
} Pero por alguna Razon no me termina de hacer lo que quiero que es buscar e eliminar unos registros en otra hoja

Answer (score 8):

Puedes utilizar el tipo de dato [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) que no permite valores duplicados.

```js
let duplicados = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7]
let unicos = Array.from(new Set(duplicados))
console.log(unicos)
```

Comment: Interesante respuesta, no estaría demás una explicación de como funciona.

Comment: Basicamente el tipo de objecto Set no permite valores duplicados, para leer un poco más sobre el puedes hacer uso de la documenaciòn https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set

Comment: gracias, aunque sugería poner la explicación como parte de la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

**Con Sort y Filter**

Puedes ordenar el `array` con `sort` y borrar cada elemento que sea igual que el anterior con `filter`

```js
const productos = ["Naranjas","Peras","Aceite","Tomate","Champu","Aceite"];

function borrar(arr) {
    return arr.sort().filter(function(ProductoActual, PosicionActual, arry) {
        return !PosicionActual || ProductoActual != arry[PosicionActual - 1];
    })
 }

const productos2 = borrar(productos);

console.info(productos2);
```

Comment: La respuesta es interesante, puedes agregar una explicación del código para mejorar la calidad.

Answer (score 2):

A todas las respuestas anteriores quería sumar tu función original modificada (le aplique unas correcciones para que funcione de la forma esperada), y finalmente propongo otra basada en la función reduce (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).

Antes de continuar con mis dos soluciones podrías inspeccionar este post: https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c, el cual muestra tres formas simples de eliminar duplicados (en las respuestas anteriores ya te han mostrado algunas de ellas):

```js
const ds = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd']

// Usando la función Set
console.log('Usando Set ' + JSON.stringify(
  [ ...new Set(ds) ]
))

// Usando la función Filter
console.log('Usando Filter ' + JSON.stringify(
  // Lo que hace es comparar un elemento actual con los que pasaron en
  // la comparación, si el indice es el de uno de los que pasaron, entonces
  // necesariamente está duplicado.
  ds.filter((item, idx) => ds.indexOf(item) === idx)
))

// Usando la función Reduce
console.log('Usando Reduce ' + JSON.stringify(
  // Lo que hace es comparar un elemento actual con los que pasaron en
  // la comparación, si el indice es el de uno de los que pasaron, entonces
  // necesariamente está duplicado.
  ds.reduce((result, current) => {
    return result.includes(current) ? result : [ ...result, current ]
  }, [])
))
```

A continuación las soluciones que te muestro aquí son la primera basada en tu función original (con correcciones), y la segunda se basa en la función reduce, pero utilicé indexOf en lugar de includes para verificar en los resultados por los duplicados.

```js
const dataset1 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd']

// Tu función mejorada:

const originalModFunction = function (ds) {
  const idborrar = [ ...ds ]

  for (let row = 0; row < idborrar.length; row++) {
    // si es nulo ignorar, dado que fue marcado como duplicado
    if (idborrar[row] === null) {
      continue
    }
    // En esta línea ten en cuenta que revisas hacia adelante siempre, los
    // "que pasaron" ya garantizan que todos los elementos para atrás del
    // arreglo son diferentes.
    for (let nextRow = row + 1; nextRow < idborrar.length; nextRow++) { 
       if (idborrar[nextRow] === idborrar[row]) {
         idborrar[nextRow] = null
       }
    }
  }
  
  // Quita todos los nulos
  return idborrar.filter(item => item)
}

// Una variante a todas las soluciones propuestas en todas las respuestas utilizando
// solo reduce (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

const noDupsReduceFunction = function (ds) {
  return ds.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    if (accumulator.indexOf(currentValue) === -1) {
      accumulator.push(currentValue)
    }
    return accumulator
  }, [])
}

// Comparando
console.log('Resultado función original modificada: ' + JSON.stringify(originalModFunction(dataset1)))
console.log('Resultado de la función que usa reduce: ' + JSON.stringify(noDupsReduceFunction(dataset1)))
```

Comment: muy buen aporte, esperemos que esta respuesta reciba mas apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Si los eliminases en vez de dejarlos vacíos, te cambiaría la relación de los indices con valores no funcionaria bien.

Así que te propongo cargar un array con los indices de los elementos que no tienes que copiar, luego guardas en un array nuevo los valores que si que quieres, y machacas el array antiguo.

```js
var Idborrar = ['a','b','a','c','a','d','a'];
let indicesNoCargar = []
function pro (){
  for (var ib = 0; ib <= Idborrar.length; ib++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < Idborrar.length - 1; j++) {
      if (ib != j) {
        if (Idborrar[ib] == Idborrar[j]) {
          if(ib !== indicesNoCargar[indicesNoCargar.length-1])
          indicesNoCargar.push(ib);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  let idborrarNew = [];
  let j=0;
  console.log(indicesNoCargar)
  for (let i=0; i< Idborrar.length; i ++){
    if(i != indicesNoCargar[j]){
      idborrarNew.push(Idborrar[i]);  
      j++;
    }
  }
  Idborrar = idborrarNew;
}
function output() {
  for( var i = 0 ;i<Idborrar.length; i++){
    $('#mu').append(Idborrar[i]+'-');
  }
}
pro();
output();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "m">
  ['a','b','a','c','a','d','a'];
</div>
<div id= "mu">
</div>
```

Comment: Me queda la duda, de si quieres mostrar la a solo una vez, o ninguna, por que es un elemento repetido

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solución usando `splice` y recorriendo menos el arreglo que lo necesario pues en la iteración anidada no hay necesidad de recorrer desde el inicio. Se altera el arreglo original y se eliminan los elementos. Al no usar `indexOf` también se minimizan los recorridos implícitos.

```js
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7];
let i = 0;
while (i < a.length) {
 let j = i + 1;
 while (j < a.length) {
  if (a[i] == a[j])
   a.splice(j,1);
  else
   j++;
 }
 i++;
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando **Set** también puedes eliminar valores repetidos de dos *arrays*:

```js
const union = (a, b) => Array.from(new Set([...a, ...b]));
console.log(union([1, 2, , 3, 3, 3], [4, 3, 2]));
console.log(union([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/273733/146637) ya menciona el uso de *Set*.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución más elemental sin usar ninguno de los recursos mencionados anteriormente y teniendo en cuenta que **sólamente funcionaría para arrays de tipo `int`** podría ser esta.

Básicamente `excluyeDuplicado` recibe como parámetro de entrada 2 arrays. Uno de ellos `a` es el array donde vienen comprendidos todos los números (con duplicado) y el otro `b`  es un array 'mapa' con la misma longitud de `a`.

Como resultado te devuelve `numerosUnicos` que es un array donde vienen comprendidos todos los números de `a` sin duplicar.

En el ejemplo he realizado la prueba con 30000 números aleatorios y he calculado el tiempo de ejecución de la función, para que se vea que el proceso es realmente rápido.

```js
function excluyeDuplicado(a, b) {
    let numerosUnicos = [];
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        let num = ListaNumeros[i];
            if(b[num] == 0) {
                b[num] = 1;
                numerosUnicos.push(num);
            } else if (b[num] == 1) {
                b[num] = 2;
            }
    }  
    
  console.log("Números únicos: " + numerosUnicos.length);
  return numerosUnicos; // array con números sin repetir

}

var ListaNumeros = new Array();
var numRandom = 30000;

for(let i=0; i<numRandom; i++) {
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * numRandom) + 1);
    ListaNumeros.push(x);
}

var mapa = new Array(ListaNumeros.length).fill(0);

var t0 = performance.now();
excluyeDuplicado(ListaNumeros, mapa);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Llamada a excluyeDuplicado con " + numRandom + " números ha tardado: " + (t1 - t0) + " milisegundos.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinventando la rueda puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma...

```
    let a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3,4,5,1];
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let elem = a[i];
        for(let j = i-1; j >= 0; j--){
            if(elem == a[j]){
                a.splice(j,1);
            }
        }           
    }
    console.log(a); //[0,2,3,4,5,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro una forma muy profesional de hacerla;

```
//Eliminar elemento Duplicados del siguiente Array (Arreglo)
let miArreglo = [10, "React", "JavaScript", 10, "PHP", 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, "React"];
let noDuplicados = new Set(miArreglo);
console.log(noDuplicados);
```

Link para que veas varias formas de hacerlo
https://github.com/urian121/Eliminar-elementos-repetidos-de-un-Array-JavaScript