# Eliminar caracteres repetidos en un string con javascript

Tags: javascript, array, string, algoritmos

Estaba realizando una ***función que dados 2 strings de caracteres, mostrara el mayor string de caracteres no repetidos ordenados***. Estuve buscando información en la página y no encontré para javascript como hacer para **eliminar caracteres que se repiten de un string**.

Código actual del problema:

```js
function longest(c1, c2) {
   
    let cadena1 = c1.split('')
        .sort()
        .filter((letra, index, self) => (
            self.indexOf(letra) === index
        )).join('');
    
    let cadena2= c2.split('')
        .sort().filter((letra, index, self) => (
            self.indexOf(letra) === index
        )).join('');

    if(cadena1.length >= cadena2.length){
        return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena1
    }else{
        return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena2
    }
    
}

var cadena1="azbyrcd";
var cadena2="asdfggggggdddddddddddxxxxxdddgxxdgdxxxxx";

var masLargo = longest(cadena1, cadena2);

console.log(masLargo);
```

Comment: Pregunta relacionada [Eliminar elementos repetidos de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273597/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-los-valores-repetido-de-un-arreglo/273620#273620)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te dejo una alternativa con la que no necesitas ampliar el prototipo de Array, `javascript` ya ofrece el objeto `Set`, que devuelve los valores únicos de un iterable. O sea, que `[...new Set(myArray)]`te devolverá un Array con los valores únicos del Array inicial.

Una vez hecho esto, lo único que tienes que hacer es evaluar qué array de caracteres es más largo y devolverlo ordenado, no tiene sentido ordenar los dos arrays ni unirlos hasta que termines de operar con ellos, así que lo puedes dejar para la clausula `return` de tu función.

Te dejo aquí el ejemplo.

```js
const string1 = 'azbyrcd';
const string2 = 'asdfggggggdddddddddddxxxxxdddgxxdgdxxxxx';

const longest = (str1, str2) => {
  const str1Unique = [...new Set(str1.split(''))];
  const str2Unique = [...new Set(str2.split(''))];
  
  const result = str1Unique.length >= str2Unique.length 
  ? str1Unique 
  : str2Unique;
  
  return result.sort().join('')
}

console.log(`La cadena más larga es ${longest(string1, string2)}`);
```

**EDIT:** Si lo que quieres es eliminar por completo el valor del string, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const string1 = 'azbyrcd';
const string2 = 'asdfggggggdddddddddddxxxxxdddgxxdgdxxxxx';

const removeAndSortAllRepeatedCharacters = str => {
  const strUnique = [...new Set(str.split(''))];
  return strUnique.filter(
    el => str.split('')
    .filter(
      char => el === char).length === 1
    )
    .sort()
    .join('');
}

const longest = (str1, str2) => {
  const str1Unique = removeAndSortAllRepeatedCharacters(str1);
  const str2Unique = removeAndSortAllRepeatedCharacters(str2);
  
  const result = str1Unique.length >= str2Unique.length 
  ? str1Unique 
  : str2Unique;
  
  return result;
}

console.log(`La cadena 1 es ${string1}, sus cadena de valores únicos es ${removeAndSortAllRepeatedCharacters(string1)}`);

console.log(`La cadena 2 es ${string2}, sus cadena de valores únicos es ${removeAndSortAllRepeatedCharacters(string2)}`);

console.log(`La cadena más larga es ${longest(string1, string2)}`);
```

Comment: Muy buena tu funcion @FernadoCarrascosa me parece mas optimizada..  si quiero eliminar por completo el caracter que se repite me sirve el Set??

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es eliminar los valores repetidos y no dejarlos, ¿no? O sea, si un el string es `aabccdee` se quede solo en `bd`, ¿no?

Comment: Te he dejado un **EDIT** en la respuesta en el que se muestra como eliminar por completo los valores repetidos.

Comment: si eso era para probar... PERO mira lo que encontre @FernadoCarrascosa sucede algo que no se como es corri la funcion con estos string "loopingisfunbutdangerous", "lessdangerousthancoding" el resultado deberia ser "abcdefghilnoprstu" no es verdad?? la funcion me devuelve esto "abdefgilnoprstu"  me falta la c y la h pq??

Comment: y me sucede lo mismo con la funcion de @the-breaker porque??? Con algunos strings me pasa

Comment: Porque lo que devuelve esta funcion es la lista de valores únicos ordenados de la string con más valores únicos.

Comment: `loopingisfunbutdangerous` tiene 15 caracteres únicos, mientras que `lessdangerousthancoding` tiene 14 caracteres únicos, por eso toma los caracteres de la primera, entre los que no hay ni "c" ni "h".

Comment: Si tienes razon gracias de nuevo @FernandoCarrascosa :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes reducir varias lineas de código con otra función que elimine los elementos repetidos del array, por ejemplo declarando esta función `unique()`:

```js
function longest(c1, c2) {

    let cadena1 = c1.split('').unique();
    
    let cadena2= c2.split('').unique();

    if(cadena1.length <= cadena2.length)
        cadena1=cadena2;
    return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena1.sort().join('')
}

Array.prototype.unique=function(a){
  return function(){return this.filter(a)}}(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)==b
});

var cadena1="azbyrcd";
var cadena2="asdfggggggdddddddddddxxxxxdddgxxdgdxxxxx";

var masLargo = longest(cadena1, cadena2);

console.log(masLargo);
```

Con `Array.prototype` se pueden agregar nuevos métodos a todos los objetos *Array*, luego la lógica para la eliminación de repetidos es semejante a la que tenias en tu solución anterior.

Más información en la documentación:

[Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/prototype)

Luego para eliminar los elementos que se repiten basta con cambiar `c.indexOf(a)==b` por `c.indexOf(a)==b && c.indexOf(a, b+1)==-1`:

```js
function longest(c1, c2) {

    let cadena1 = c1.split('').unique();
    
    let cadena2= c2.split('').unique();

    if(cadena1.length <= cadena2.length)
        cadena1=cadena2;
    return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena1.sort().join('')
}

Array.prototype.unique=function(a){
  return function(){return this.filter(a)}}(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)==b && c.indexOf(a, b+1)==-1
});

var cadena1="qwewe";
var cadena2="assdddfg";

var masLargo = longest(cadena1, cadena2);

console.log(masLargo);
```

Espero haber ayudado a resolver el problema, saludos.

Comment: Gracias @the-breaker mucho mejor asi, dejare tu funcion como respuesta..  estaba probando algunas cosas y si quisiera eliminar por completo el caracter que se repite como pudiera hacerlo.

Comment: @IsraelGonzález quieres decir que si el carácter se repite se elimine?

Comment: si exacto.. aqui esta dejando el caracter 1 vez

Comment: @IsraelGonzález considero que debería ser otra pregunta diferente pero te adelanto que para eso basta con cambiar `c.indexOf(a)==b` por `c.indexOf(a)==b && c.indexOf(a, b+1)==-1`

Answer (score 1):

Se pueden mejorar algunas cosas pero esta es la funcion que hice..

```js
function longest(c1, c2) {
    // your code
    let cadena1 = c1.split('')
        .filter((letra, index, self) => (
            self.indexOf(letra) === index
        )).join('');
    
    let cadena2= c2.split('').filter((letra, index, self) => (
            self.indexOf(letra) === index
        )).join('');

    if(cadena1.length >= cadena2.length){
        return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena1
    }else{
        return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena2
    }
    
}

var cadena1="azbyrcd";
var cadena2="asdfggggggdddddddddddxxxxxdddgxxdgdxxxxx";

var masLargo = longest(cadena1, cadena2);

console.log(masLargo);
```

Donde con:

> c1.split('')

tomo mis strings pasados por parametros y los convierto en arreglos de la forma ['a', 'b', 'c']

> .filter((letra, index, self) => (
>               self.indexOf(letra) === index
>           ))

hago un filter al arreglo y tomo los indices de la primera aparicion de las letras..

> .join('');

convierto el arreglo a un string nuevamente..

> if(cadena1.length >= cadena2.length){
>           return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena1
>       }else{
>           return "La cadena mas larga es: "+cadena2
>       }
>   }

comparo cual es la mas larga de las dos cadenas y la devuelvo.

Answer (score 1):

El objeto `Set()` almacena **valores únicos** y la propiedad `.size` retorna la cantidad de esos valores únicos.

Usando la asignación por destructuring convertimos un `String` en un `Array` y luego en un `Set()`:

```js
const str = "abcccccccd";
const cant = new Set([..."abcccccccd"]).size;
console.log(cant);
```

Para detectar cual string tiene mayor cantidad de caracteres no repetidos, yo usaría una función general `sort()` para ordenar n strings.

```js
const strs = ['b', 'aabb', 'abcdefgefgh', 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbb'];

const ordenados = (strs) =>
  strs.sort((a, b) =>
    new Set([...b]).size -
    new Set([...a]).size
  );

console.log(ordenados(strs));
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte @Emeeus me quedo claro que el Set() es mucho mas comodo..

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*Programa una función que elimine cierto patrón de caracteres de un texto dado, 
miFuncion("xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5", "xyz") devolverá  "1, 2, 3, 4 y 5. */

function EliminaCaracteres(texto, patron) {
  var cadena = "";
  if (typeof texto === 'string') {
    var cad = texto.split(patron);
    cad.slice(0);

    cad.forEach(element => {
      cadena = cadena+element;
    });
  }else{cadena=`${texto}, No es un texto..... `}
  return cadena; 
}

console.log(EliminaCaracteres("xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5", "xyz"));
```