# Eliminar números de un arreglo si se repiten

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmos

Estoy haciendo una función que elimine los números repetidos de un arreglo (los elimine por completo y solo me devuelva aquel que no se repite).. esta es mi función que esta haciendo lo contrario.. para el ejemplo de **[1, 2, 1]** me regresa **[1]**:

```js
function noRepetido(numeros) {

    const numero = numeros.filter((numero, i, self) => (
        self.indexOf(numero) != i
    ))
    return numero;
}

console.log(noRepetido([1, 2, 1]));
```

Si en vez de usar el operador distinto `!=` utilizo el igual `===` me regresa el arreglo sin repetirse ningún numero **[1,2]** para el ejemplo.

Comment: Pero.. el que no se repite es el 2...

Comment: si me equivoque me regresa 1 lo corregi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disculpa en la mañana ya te dieron una respuesta semejante, solo había que adaptarla:

```js
function noRepetido(array){
  const strUnique = [...new Set(array)];
  return strUnique.filter(
    el => array
    .filter(
      char => el === char).length === 1
    );
}

console.log(noRepetido([1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3]));
```

Créditos a su autor, luego le paso una recompensa.

[Eliminar caracteres repetidos en un string con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/293063/77879)

Comment: si ya lo se que era muy similar pero queria añadir este caso a la pagina con una solucion simplificada con filter().. esta tambien Set() mejor  gracias de nuevo @the-breaker :)

Comment: @IsraelGonzález de nada, aunque creo que existe una opción mas con `includes()`

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usarlo así:

```js
let repetidos= [ 1,2,3,4,4,1,5,2,6];
let sinRepetir=[];
sinRepetir= repetidos.filter((valorActual, indiceActual, arreglo) => {
    return arreglo.findIndex(valorDelArreglo => JSON.stringify(valorDelArreglo) === 
    JSON.stringify(valorActual)) === indiceActual
});

console.log(sinRepetir)
```

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, agrega mas información para mejorar la calidad por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes solucionarlo recorriendo el arreglo una sola vez, así:

- Creas un objeto (`eg: checkeds`) donde registras los números ya controlados.
- Al recorrer el arreglo, validas que el número no este en el objeto y que tampoco este otra vez en el arreglo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function noRepetido(numeros) {
  let checkeds = {};
  return numeros.filter((num, i) => {
    let unique = !checkeds[num] && !numeros.includes(num, i + 1);
    checkeds[num] = true;
    return unique;
  });
}

console.log(noRepetido([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4]));
```

Comment: sabia que también se podía con `includes()`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer el uso de [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) y remover los elementos repetidos.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,5];

let unicos = new Set(arr);

console.log("Unicos: ", [...unicos]);
```

Comment: gracias @VickMuños pero quiero eliminar los q se repitieron por completo