# array.prototype.filter

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, filtro, react-hooks

Esta pregunta es más por curiosidad que necesidad.

Resulta que estaba trabajando con un array con integers y necesitaba una función de filtrado para que no se repitiesen números, al principio de todo he empezado haciéndolo de la siguiente forma.

```
        // Función que recibe el evento del botón y la posición del elemento
        const shiftSelectedNodes = (ev, position) => {
        // Busca si el elemento ya está añadido al array
        const res = nodesSelected.find(element => element === position);
        // En caso de que no esté en el array, lo añade
        if(res === undefined){
            setNodesSelected([...nodesSelected, position]);
        }else{
            // En caso de que ya exista el elemento dentro del array, quería hacer un filter
            // y crear un nuevo array con los elementos que no fuesen igual a la posición
            let filteredNodes = nodesSelected.filter(element => {
                if(element !== position){
                    return element;
                }
            });
            // Un vistazo para comprobar que todo vaya bien
            console.log(filteredNodes);
            // Esto modifica el array existente y escribe el nuevo
            setNodesSelected(filteredNodes);

        }
```

Todo parece correcto y debuggeando el interior del filter y todo, funciona correctamente, el problema viene en que el console.log del final, no me saca los resultados esperados.

Ej:

- Pulso botón en la posición 0
- nodesSelected = [0];
- Pulso botón en la posición 1
- nodeSelected = [0, 1];
- Pulso botón en la posición 2
- nodeSelected = [0, 1, 2];
- Pulso de nuevo el botón en la posición 2
- nodeSelected = [1] //Aquí está el error

La solución que he encontrado para esto es:

```
let filteredNodes = nodesSelected.filter(element => element !== position)
```

Poner todo el filter en una linea.

Y después de todo este rollo, mi pregunta es: ¿Porqué tiene este comportamiento? No entiendo que está mal en mi primer intento, no se si hay algo que se me ha pasado.

Muchas gracias y disculpen que me explique como un libro cerrado!

Comment: puedes intetar otras cosas  mira[esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/273733/28035)

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que yo pregunto, si te fijas en ningún momento tengo elementos repetidos en el array, lo que hago es comprobar si ese "indice" existe y si existe lo quito, la solución al problema la habia encontrado ya, lo que yo preguntaba es por el comportamiento de la función filter, ya he marcado la respuesta correcta a este post por si te interesa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es porque filter(), al igual que find(), espera que el return sea un valor truthy, esto es un objeto, 1, true, ' ', etc. Si no especificas un return fuera del if, el return es undefined, lo que hace que no incluya al valor en el array.

Pensemos en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].filter(x => x > 1)
```

Cuando en una función de flechita no se colocan {}, el return es lo que salga de la única línea que lo compone. No puede haber ; ni más de una línea. En este caso el return es 'Es x mayor que 1?'. Como 0 y 1 dan false, no son incluidos en el array resultante. El resto sí

Comment: Vale, cambiando un poco el codigo de función he conseguido el mismo resultado que con ella simplificada.

`let filteredNodes = nodesSelected.filter(element => {
    if(element !== position){
     return true;
    }
   })`

Comment: Sí, porque tu condición, 'element !== position' se convierte en true o false. Cuando es true pasa al arreglo filtrado, cuando es false, es excluido.