# Eliminar Datos repetidos de un Arreglo en Angular

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes acudo a ustedes debido a que tengo problemas al eliminar datos repetidos de un arreglo:
el arreglo es el siguiente:

```
datosRol = [
    {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 13, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
    {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 13, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
    {codigoRol: 2, codigoSucursal: 13, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE PHANTOMX", indexRol: 3},
    {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
    {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
    {codigoRol: 2, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE PHANTOMX", indexRol: 3},
    {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
    {codigoRol: 2, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE PHANTOMX", indexRol: 3},
    {codigoRol: 1, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE FACTURACION3", indexRol: 4}
]
```

como se ve hay datos repetidos en ese arreglo, los campos que no se deben repetir son: "codigoRol" y "codigoSucursal":

he visto funciones como "unique" pero no me sirven existira alguna funcion en angular que elimine los datos repetidos de un arreglo?, agradeceria mucho su ayuda porque he estado tanto tiempo en este problema

Comment: deberias concretar un poco como quieres quitar los datos repetidos. Indicar el campo que tiene que ser unique, por ejemplo dejar quitar todos aquellos que tengas el mismo `codigoRol`?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta los datos que no se deben repetir son codigorol y codigosucursal

Comment: [Busca en esta pregunta del stack overflow en inglés] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: que intentastes para resolver el lo que quieres

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar elementos repetidos de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273597/eliminar-elementos-repetidos-de-un-array)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion map para esto:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    const datosRol = [
        {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 13, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
        {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 13, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
        {codigoRol: 2, codigoSucursal: 13, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE PHANTOMX", indexRol: 3},
        {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
        {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
        {codigoRol: 2, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE PHANTOMX", indexRol: 3},
        {codigoRol: 17, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "TESTA DW FINAN 5", indexRol: 2},
        {codigoRol: 2, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE PHANTOMX", indexRol: 3},
        {codigoRol: 1, codigoSucursal: 12, nombreRol: "ADMINISTRADOR DE FACTURACION3", indexRol: 4}
    ]

    let datosRolSinRepetir = [];

    datosRol.map((datoRol, i) => {
        i == 0 ? datoRol : datosRolSinRepetir.filter(sinRep => {
            return sinRep.codigoRol === datoRol.codigoRol && sinRep.codigoSucursal === datoRol.codigoSucursal
        }).length == 0 ? datosRolSinRepetir.push(datoRol) : datoRol
    });

    console.log(datosRolSinRepetir);
}
```

Basicamente lo que hacemos aquí:

```
    let datosRolSinRepetir = [];

    datosRol.map((datoRol, i) => {
        i == 0 ? datoRol : datosRolSinRepetir.filter(sinRep => {
            return sinRep.codigoRol === datoRol.codigoRol && sinRep.codigoSucursal === datoRol.codigoSucursal
        }).length == 0 ? datosRolSinRepetir.push(datoRol) : datoRol
    });
```

Es crear un arreglo que contendra los elementos sin repetir, seguidamente, iteramos sobre el arreglo original y metemos siempre de primeras el primer elemento, para tener una referencia de donde empezar, luego dentro, comprobamos si estamos en la primera iteración, en caso de que no sea así, quiere decir que el arreglo `datosRolSinRepetir` ya tiene contenido, así que seguidamente lo que hacemos es hacer un filter, atravez de este array, para así tener una referencía de que elementos ya estan y poder hacer una comparación entre ellos, para esto esta esta condición:

```
return sinRep.codigoRol === datoRol.codigoRol && sinRep.codigoSucursal === datoRol.codigoSucursal
```

Donde comprobamos que ambas propiedades, en ambos arreglos sean iguales entre ellas, en caso contrario el arreglo resultado tendra como minimo un elemento, por lo cual no nos interesa agregar este elemento al arreglo `datosRolSinRepetir` sin embargo, si al ejecutarse la función filter, da como resultado que el arreglo tiene 0 elementos, es decir esta vació, entonces quiere decir que ese elemento aún no esta en nuestra lista de `datosRolSinRepetir` por lo cuál lo añadimos, es así como funciona este metodo.

Comment: Quice hacerlo así con map para mas elegancia, pero aviso de una vez que esto es totalmente modificable, para que en vez de usar filter dentro del map, usar por ejemplo un for y comenzar desde cierto indice... para así no tener que estar recorriendo el array todo el tiempo... así sería mucho mas eficiente, sin embargo de primeras este metodo hace exactamente aquello que buscas.