# Eliminar arreglo solo si está repetido

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

Tengo un arreglo en Javascript que contiene otros arreglos en su interior. Mi pregunta sería como eliminar un arreglo si aparece repetido en el arreglo que los contiene. Así:

**Input:**

```
[["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"], ["#000", "Negro"]]
```

**Output**

```
[["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"]]
```

*Aclaración*: Para ser considerado repetido tiene que estar más de una vez en el array, y lo que quiero es que solamente quede una vez ese array repetido. Y si, el orden influye, es decir: `["Black", "#000"]` y `["#000","Black"]` serían elementos distintos.

*Lo que he estado probando*: He probado usar el objeto `Set` pero me di cuenta que no funciona con Arrays, sino que solo funciona con elementos dentro de un Array. También usé los métodos `filter` y `forEach` pero no conseguí nada.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar elementos repetidos de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273597/eliminar-elementos-repetidos-de-un-array)

Comment: No, ya que necesito que se elimine el Array en cuestión, no los elementos que haya adentro de él. De hecho esa es una de las preguntas que usé al momento de investigar como solucionar el problema.

Comment: Podrás definir qué tiene que ocurrir para ser considerado "repetido"? El primer item repetido? Siempre lleva 2  items y ambos repetidos? en cualquier orden o en el mismo orden? o cada array puede tener múltiples elementos de cualquier tipo?

Comment: Para ser considerado repetido tiene que estar más de una vez en el array, y lo que quiero es que solamente quede una vez ese array repetido. Y si, el orden influye, es decir: `["Black", "#000"]` y `["#000","Black"]` serían elementos distintos. @Pollo

Comment: Al margen de tus comentarios aclaratorios (quito voto de cierre por duplicado), anexa que has hecho de otro modo tu pregunta no muestra punto de partida o lo que llevas hecho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un array no se puede comparar por igualdad con otro. `["a"] == ["a"]` devuelve siempre `false` porque son *instancias* diferentes. La mejor forma es usar un bucle que compara todos los elementos (cantidad, tipo y valor)... Pero no voy a responder con la mejor forma.

Esta forma es un tanto rústica y claramente no será la de mejor performance, pero me gusta usar para este caso.

1. Convierte cada elemento del array a un string JSON (desventaja en performance, ventaja en que acepta cualquier objeto/array)
2. Genera un [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) (que siempre tiene elementos únicos -pequeña ventaja)
   Acá si bien estamos garantizando que sean únicos, lo que estamos haciendo es utilizando la representación como JSON. Es decir, estamos comparando strings.
3. Lo lleva a array usando sintaxis [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread).
4. Vuelve a convertir de JSON al array/objeto original

```js
function distinct(array){
    return [...new Set(
                array.map(JSON.stringify)
           )]
           .map(JSON.parse);
}



//Prueba
let prueba = [
              ["#FFF", "Blanco"],
              ["#000", "Negro"],
              ["#000", "Negro"],
              ["Negro", "#000"]
             ],
    pruebaDistinct = distinct(prueba);


console.log(pruebaDistinct);
//--> [
//     ["#FFF", "Blanco"],
//     ["#000", "Negro"],
//     ["Negro", "#000"]
//    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

podes combinar el uso del `forEach` con el `findIndex`
y aprovechar los parametros opcionales de ambos ( indice para este caso )
el findIndex corta en la devolucion de un true pasado por condicion pero para el caso antes de retornar el true evaluas en una condicion si los elementos son iguales , fijate que estan evaluandose como strings y ademas que no se este evaluando asi mismo `indice!=index` espero que te sirva , saludos!

```js
const arr = [["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"], ["#000", "Negro"]]

arr.forEach((elemento, indice )=>{
    arr.findIndex((item,index)=>{
        if(`${elemento}`==`${item}` && indice!=index){
            arr.splice(indice,1)
            return true
        }
    })

})

console.log(arr);
```

---

### Aclaracion

Solo va a limpiar si se repite una vez con el `findIndex` , si buscas que se eliminen todos los repetidos podrias tranquilamente volver a llamar a `foreach` y sacar el `return`

Comment: Está muy bien el método, pero hay un caso raro en el que fallaría: al convertir a string, estás uniendo con comas los elementos, lo cual sería un problema si se presenta algo como https://jsfiddle.net/rpsn5cvq/

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa puede ser

puedes usar un Set para hacer la búsqueda, pasando cada elemento a String y guardandolos en el Set, al estar en String se guardara solo una vez.

Si cada elemento del arreglo al buscarlo en el Set no existe es por que es la primer incidencia, si en las demas iteraciones lo encuentras es que el objeto que se encuentra en el indice actual ya fue encontrado, por lo cual esta repetido y no formara parte del array resultado.

```js
let arr = [["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"], ["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"], ["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"], ["#FFF", "Blanco"], ["#000", "Negro"], ["#FFF", "Blanco"]]
const auxArr = new Set();
const arrRes = [];

arr.forEach( element => {
    const el = element.toString();
    if (!auxArr.has(el)) {
        arrRes.push(element);
        auxArr.add(el);
    }
});
arr = arrRes;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: En este caso, arr es un arreglo que contiene otros arrays, por lo cual el pasar el objeto a Base64 hace mas sencillo verificar si dos o mas objetos de este array son iguales

Comment: Fijate que al convertir a string, es lo mismo que unir con comas... Y acá la prueba de cuando fallaría el código: https://jsfiddle.net/yfebojs4/

Comment: como dice @Pollo en su respuesta, todo se basa en pasar a json, si cambiara el toString por JSON.stringify(element) no fallaria, gracias.

Comment: ese Pollo es un tipo raro