# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar textos aleatorios con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo acá un código con Jquery que reutilice de otro sitio mio, muestra textos ordenados (con un Fadeout, etc..), pero está vez quiero mostrar textos aleatoriamente pero no logro como hacerlo y en donde modificar.

```
var $m = jQuery.noConflict();
    // Use jQuery via $j(...)
    $m(document).ready(function() {
        //Did you know widget
        max = parseInt(5);
        cur = parseInt(2);
        var Facts = {};
        Facts[1] = "<span class='txt1'>¿Qué comeremos hoy?, mmmm...</span>";
        Facts[2] = "<span class='txt2'>¡Diversión al límite!, te cansarás rápido...</span>";
        Facts[3] = "<span class='txt3'>Uniendo piezas, acomodando furnis y arreglando wireds...</span>";
        Facts[4] = "<span class='txt4'>¡Shazam!, ¿ya la has visto?...</span>";
        setInterval(function() {
            if (cur + 1 <= 4) {
                cur = cur + 1;
            } else {
                cur = 1;
            }
            newText = Facts[cur];
            $m('#loader-text').fadeOut(function() {
                $m('#loader-text').html(newText);
                $m('#loader-text').fadeIn();
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow pregunto desde la ignorancia, pero la función `Math` no aplicaría sólo para números?

Comment: Math para los numero que son los indices

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera como dice x-rw la idea es que tenga un valor aleatorio de la longitud del array; una vez obtenido el valor puede acceder a esa posicion del array

Comment: @JackNavaRow, algunos textos se repiten, cosa que no quiero. La idea es que de textos aleatorios sin repetirse

Comment: la respuesta que te envie tiene el algoritmo para que no se repita el indice

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-generar-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    var $m = jQuery.noConflict();
        // Use jQuery via $j(...)
        $m(document).ready(function() {
            //Did you know widget
            max = parseInt(5);
            cur = parseInt(2);
            var Facts = [];
            Facts[0] = "<span class='txt1'>¿Qué comeremos hoy?, mmmm...</span>";
            Facts[1] = "<span class='txt2'>¡Diversión al límite!, te cansarás rápido...</span>";
            Facts[2] = "<span class='txt3'>Uniendo piezas, acomodando furnis y arreglando wireds...</span>";
            Facts[3] = "<span class='txt4'>¡Shazam!, ¿ya la has visto?...</span>";
            Facts = Facts.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});
            setInterval(function() {
            
                cur++; // incrementamos en 1
                if( cur == Facts.length) {
                    cur=0;
                }
                newText = Facts[cur];
                $m('#loader-text').fadeOut(function() {
                    $m('#loader-text').html(newText);
                    $m('#loader-text').fadeIn();
                });
            }, 5000);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='loader-text'></p>
```

Comment: Se me repite algunos textos, cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: @SrArepa el problema es que los indices deben comenzar en `0` y tu los inicializas en `1` ya hice la correccion saludos.