# Generar 10 números en Javascript dentro de un bucle entre 0 y 20

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:  En este ejercicio tendrás que generar 10 números aleatorios que estén comprendidos entre 0 y 20 haciendo uso de un bucle.

De momento he sacado este código ya:

```
var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*21)
console.log("Número aleatorio entre 0 y 20:"+aleatorio);
```

Me va dando números alteatórios de 0 a 20, pero necesitaría que se me diera 10 números y no sólo 1.

¿Alguién puede decirme como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Pues coges ese código y lo pones dentro de un bucle for, tal como reza el enunciado.  Encontrarás información sobre el bucle for en este [enlace](https://www.google.es/search?q=javscript+for). Tendrás que vigilar no repetir el número, por tanto ponlo en un array si no existe previamente el dato.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que iterarlo dentro de un bucle:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*21);
  console.log("Número aleatorio entre 0 y 20:" + aleatorio);
}
```

Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es que no se repitan puedes ejecutar algo similar a esto:

```
//Define la cantidad de numeros aleatorios.
var cantidadNumeros = 10;
var myArray = []
while(myArray.length < cantidadNumeros ){
  var numeroAleatorio = Math.ceil(Math.random()*cantidadNumeros);
  var existe = false;
  for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    if(myArray [i] == numeroAleatorio){
        existe = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(!existe){
    myArray[myArray.length] = numeroAleatorio;
  }

}
document.write("números aleatorios : " + myArray);
```

> La parte de los números no repetidos es parte de la respuesta de este hilo [¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-generar-n%C3%BAmeros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan)

Comment: ¿y si se repite? Bueno, da igual, basicamente aqui no deberiamos hacer los ejercicios de nadie.

Comment: Me he precipitado en la respuesta, con sólo buscar un poco ya se encuentran miles de soluciones: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-generar-n%C3%BAmeros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan

Comment: Muchas grácias, sabia que tenía que poner un bucle for, pero no me funcionaba, lo estaba poniendo mal. En cuanto a lo de repetirse, eso no importa... en el enunciado no aparece que no se deba repetir

Comment: Edito mi respuesta para añadir la funcionalidad de números no repetidos XD