# Eliminar números repetidos de un random

Tags: javascript, array, random

Tengo un random el cual da números entre 0 y 12, y quiero que el numero que vaya saliendo se elimine del random. Por ejemplo si sale un 1, que no pueda volver a salir un 1.

Mi código actual es este:

```js
var cartas = [];

function barajear() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  cartas[i]=barajear();
}

console.log(cartas);
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo generar números aleatorios que no se repitan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26977/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-generar-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-que-no-se-repitan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes apoyarte de un array de números del 1 al 10, en donde en cada bucle obtenemos un número aleatorio dependiendo a la longitud del array (si su longitud es de 10, obtenemos un número aleatorio del 1 al 10), ese número aleatorio lo interpretamos como su índice y posteriormente eliminamos el índice aleatorio para que nunca se repitan, ya que el elemento de cada índice son números diferentes, por ejemplo (explicación en comentarios):

```js
var cartas = [];

var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function barajear() {
  // retorno un número del 1 hasta "numeros.length", ya que en cada bucle eliminamos un elemento.
  // o sea en el primer bucle tenemos un número aleatorio del 1 al 10...
  // en el segundo bucle, un número del 1 al 9... sucesivamente.
  // los números pueden repetir, pero como trabajaremos con índices, retornamos el elemento de
  // ese índice, y como todos los elementos son diferentes, nunca van a ser iguales.
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * numeros.length);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // Aquí obtengo el número aleatorio que me devuelve el método "barajear()".
  var indiceAleatorio = barajear();
  // Interpretamos el número aleatorio como un índice del array "numeros", y de ese índice,
  // capturamos su elemento, y ese elemento capturado lo asignamos al array "cartas".
  cartas[i] = numeros[indiceAleatorio];
  // Y el índice aleatorio que nos devuelve el método "barajear()", lo eliminamos del array "numeros"
  // para que no se repita en los bucles posteriores.
  numeros.splice(indiceAleatorio, 1);
}

console.log(cartas);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema de conseguir valores aleatorios sin repetirlos, tiene muchas soluciones distintas dependiendo de la naturaleza del problema.
En este caso, que mezclas "cartas" (valores del 1 al 10), una solución simple es crear un array nuevo e ir añadiendo valores al azar mientras los eliminar del primero.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var cartas=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function mezclar(baraja){
  var barajaMezclada=[];
  while (baraja.length>0){ // Mientras queden cartas...
    let posicion=Math.floor(Math.random()*baraja.length); // Elegir carta
    barajaMezclada.push(baraja[posicion]); // Añadir en resultado
    baraja.splice(posicion,1); // Eliminar de la lista
  }
  return barajaMezclada;
}

cartas=mezclar(cartas);
document.write(cartas);
```