# ¿Cómo extraigo imagenes random de un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito de su ayuda para extraer imagenes aleatorias de un array al abrir la pagina o recargándola.
Les dejo el codigo

```
function aleatorio( num0 ) {
    return(Math.floor(Math.random() * num0 + 1 ));
}
var imagenes2da = new Array();
imagenes2da[0] = "../img/ITEMS/gauntlets_lg.png";
imagenes2da[1] = "../img/ITEMS/circlet_lg.png";
imagenes2da[2] = "../img/ITEMS/clarity_lg.png";
imagenes2da[3] = "../img/ITEMS/mantle_lg.png";
imagenes2da[4] = "../img/ITEMS/boots_lg.png";
imagenes2da[5] = "../img/ITEMS/slippers_lg.png";
imagenes2da[6] = "../img/ITEMS/recipe_lg.png";
imagenes2da[7] = "../img/ITEMS/gloves.png";

function cambiar() {
    $("#imagenes").src = imagenes2da[aleatorio(imagenes2da.length)-1];
}
```

Codigo HTML (intento con un boton)

```
<div><img id="imagenes" alt="Imagen aleatoria" src="../img/ITEMS/ancient_janggo_lg.png"></div>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="cambiar()"></a>
```

También he intentado esto con html, pero no da resultado

```
<div><img id="imagenes" onload="cambiar()" alt="Imagen aleatoria" src="../img/ITEMS/ancient_janggo_lg.png"></div>
```

Comment: Mirate esta pregunta, es similar a los que buscas, si los strings son direcciones de archivos ya lo tienes.
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22857/extraer-4-strings-random-de-un-array-en-javascript/22861#22861

Comment: Buen día, aquí puedes hacer preguntas pero, debes tener algo realizado, parte del código que genere tu problema, te lo digo de buena manera :)
A muchos aquí les molesta esta clase de preguntas. Edítala, y muestra qué tienes hecho, es posible que si sabes preguntar te responderán aunque lo que tengas sea poco :) Te di +1 porque yo también empecé con preguntas como la tuya, y porque también pensé que aquí me hacian todo el trabajo. Espero tengas un excelente día.

Comment: creo que tenes un error en esta linea     **$("#imagenes").src = imagenes2da[aleatorio(imagenes2da.length)-1]; **  , no es asi , deberia ser asi -> $("#imagenes").attr("src" ,imagenes2da[aleatorio(imagenes2da.length)-1]); busca sobre la funcion attr en jquery ,que sirve para agregar un atributo a un objeto. No le estas asignado bien el atributo SRC.

Comment: @SergioRomero muchas gracias, me has sacado de un dolor de cabeza!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como @SergioRomero dijo en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36288/c%C3%B3mo-extraigo-imagenes-random-de-un-array-en-javascript#comment61094_36288), el error esta en como asignas el `src`.

> Para cambiar el atributo `src` de un
>    objeto `jQuery`, debes usar [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
function cambiar() {
  $("#imagenes").attr('src', imagenes2da[aleatorio(imagenes2da.length)-1]);
}
```

Aquí una demo:

```js
$(function() {
  
  var imagenes = [
    '//www.tosbase.com/content/img/icons/items/icon_item_gloves_sr_olive.png',
    '//www.tosbase.com/content/img/icons/items/icon_item_boots_sr_olive.png',
    '//www.tosbase.com/content/img/icons/items/icon_item_pants_sr_olive.png',
    '//www.tosbase.com/content/img/icons/items/icon_item_shirts_sr_olive.png'
  ];
  
  function obtenerImagenAleatoria() {
    return imagenes[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagenes.length)];
  }
  
  function cambiarImagen() {
    $('#imagen').attr('src', obtenerImagenAleatoria());
  }
  
  // Imagen inicial
  cambiarImagen();

  // Eventos
  $('#boton').on('click', cambiarImagen);
});
```

```html
<img id="imagen" alt="Imagen aleatoria"><br/>
<button id="boton" type="button">Cambiar imagen</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```